# Must I always use v-html/v-pre for displaying user input? Vue JS

Tags: vue.js

I ran into an issue where Vue threw errors that x wasn't defined if I tried displaying user content such as:

```
<span><%= field.content %></span>
```

This is ruby which processes server side, it would output something like: `"Hi, it's {{todays_date}} today."` which Vue would then process. `{{todays_date}}` is not intended to be parsed by Vue, but is rather intended as a domain specific language.

I then read up on v-pre and that works to escape the content:

```
<span v-pre><%= field.content %></span>
```

However, I now realize that anywhere I'm displaying the user content throughout the entire app could have the same issue. When it breaks, it breaks the entire site.

Note that the ruby syntax is to provide context, but really it could be any database field output that is derived from user input.

What is the best way to handle this? It seems like overkill to use v-pre on every single view where I'm displaying user input.

Comment: Is that EJS syntax?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights no that is server side rendering via Ruby on Rails.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I suppose for the sake of this post, I could have put what the server side content would render, though I thought having the context of the user input variable might be helpful.

Comment: If you mix several DSLs into one template, then yes, you'll need to make sure that one doesn't process the other/one it's not supposed to process. If you wanted to literally include "`{{ something }}`" in your Vue template, you'd need to prevent Vue from processing it with `v-pre`. The same is true whether you dynamically create that template or do so manually. Either you ensure Ruby-side that nothing will be output that resembles Vue template syntax, or you need to add `v-pre`. Or try not to mix two different template systems together in the first place.

Comment: @deceze thanks for the advice. Even if it weren't a domain specific language type of input, but rather just a free-text input, sometimes users might use {{ }} as input. That could be the case with any text input throughout our entire app (hundreds!). With that said, are you confirming that the only way to handle this is either by 1) Use server side to process out or escape {{ }} or 2) use v-pre on all elements that display user input content.. ?

Comment: Also, feel free to post as an answer. I know it's more or less philosophical, but I think an important question to answer.

Comment: The thing with a template is that you hardcode certain parts, the parts you type yourself, and other parts get filled in at runtime by the template engine. What you’re doing is *generating a template with a template*, which is by definition going to be extra annoying. Why can’t Vue do *all* the work, including whatever Ruby is doing? Then you’d just need to send data to Vue and not worry about meta-escaping. If you do want this two-step process, then yes, you have enumerated your options.

Comment: @deceze well, the application I'm working on is unique in that it is still a multi-page app, but uses VueJS for various enhancements. With that said, I wrapped the entire layout in the vue app, so anywhere in the rendered view I can add Vue components. So, there are several places where Ruby on Rails is just rendering content inside the global Vue app.

Comment: Then you’ll need to live with a lot of escaping one way or the other.